# how to be notified that items of the array are updated?

Tags: c#

Assume I have some array. All items are initially `null`
Thread1 writes to array. Thread2 blocks until all items in array are set (and then process).

I was doing it like that: I've created one another array with `AutoResetEvent`. In Thread1 every time i update array item i call `Set` to corresponding AutoResetEvent and in Thread2 I just `WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);`

But now I do think this is not efficient. I think that I should probably use **one** event. Because I can count how many items are updated yet, i can just raise event on last update.

This is simplified exmple, in real life things are a little bit harder, but probably you can suggest something better?

Also should I use `Volatile.Read` in Thread1? (I have double-CPU machine).

Answer (score 0):

What not take a look at a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) so you can add your items in a thread safe manner?

You could look at using a [thread safe ObserveableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899940/is-there-a-threadsafe-observable-collection-in-net-4) to get your notifications too.

Comment: how will help it to replace "WaitAll"?

Comment: also I would prefer "simplest" solution. because i do care about latency and because i will port that to c++ in future.

Comment: you could use the Task approach http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx