# Thread safe ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, uwp, thread-safety, observablecollection

I'm searching for a thread safe `ObservableCollection` and i found this example here on stackoverflow:
[Thread safe ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309018/8237474)

But my `public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;` object always is null.
Is there something missing in the example or do i miss something?
Or is there an even better solution for this?

Sorry that im asking a new question for this but i can't answer to that comment.

Thanks

Comment: It's null because no one is subscribed to it. You can use `public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = new delegate { };` trick or just add null checks where CollectionChanged is called.

Comment: That is what i was thinking too, but where to subscribe to that event, when i'm using the `ObservableConcurrentBag`. If i check for null and skip the call, the call will be skipped every time i modify the collection.